# How to a team system ? (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

im trying to make a tag game that one player from the spectate team or nutural team will be chosen to be the tag and another will be chosen to be the runner. They'll both teleport to a small map, there the tag will have to try catch the runner before the times up.
Now my problem is that when the player loads to the game he does'nt autoassigned to the nuturalteam(spectateteam) and also when the players tp to the map they wont change the teams to a tager and runner they'll both be in the same team. Help will be appriciated!
Also i dont get any errors in the outpot besides "loadstring is not availble".
Here is the round system script:

````
Teams = game:GetService("Teams")
local SpectateTeam = game.Teams.Spectate
local ItTeam = game.Teams.It
local RunnerTeam = game.Teams.Runner
local roundlength = 5
local intermissionLength = 4
local inRound = game.ReplicatedStorage.InRound
local Status = game.ReplicatedStorage.Status
local LobbySpawn = workspace.Map.SpawnLobby
local MapSpawnIt = workspace.Map.SpawnMapIt
local MapSpawnRunner = workspace.Map.SpawnMapRunner
local frame = game.StarterGui.ScreenGuimenu.Frame
local KillerSpawn = workspace.Map.SpawnMapIt
local lobbyspace = workspace.Lobbyspace


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.Team = SpectateTeam
end)

inRound.Changed:Connect(function(player)
    if inRound.Value == true then
        local chosen = Players:GetChildren()[math.random(1, #Players:GetChildren())]
        print(" is It")
        chosen.Team = ItTeam
        local runner = SpectateTeam:GetPlayers()[math.random(1, #Players:GetChildren())]
        print(" is Runner")
    runner.Team = Teams.Runner
        wait()
                runner.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = MapSpawnRunner.CFrame
                chosen.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = KillerSpawn.CFrame
                
        end
        
    if inRound.Value == false then
        for _, player in pairs(game.Players:GetChildren(player)) do
            local char = player.Character
            char.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = LobbySpawn.CFrame
            player.Team = SpectateTeam
        end
    end
end)




local function RoundTimer()
    while wait() do
        for i = intermissionLength, 0, -1 do
            inRound.Value = false
            wait(1)
            Status.Value = "Intermission:" .. i .."seconds left!"
        end
        for i = roundlength, 0, -1 do
            inRound.Value = true
            wait(1)
            Status.Value = "Game:" .. i .."seconds left!"
        end
    end
end

spawn(RoundTimer) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! i just forgot to sync the color of the teams with the spawns :)